# How to make <input type="email"> a textarea?

Tags: html

I want Multiple Emails in a single textarea. Textarea type="email" doesn't work at all.
I want to accept multiple Emails separated by `,` (comma) in a textarea and I wish to validate each of them.
What can be the solution for this problem?

Comment: So do you want to validate, if the user enters an Email ?

Comment: You have choice of textearea and have to use javascript to validate emails then? OR you can use some plugin to simplify your job.

Comment: Why do you want a multi-line input area to enter an email address?

Comment: Because I have multiple emails separated by comma in input field. Validation for multiple email is given by html. I just want to use text area for email as in text (like <textarea>)

Comment: There's no way to do this without validating the addresses yourself. By the way, if you intend to allow multiple email addresses, then you should make that clear in your question, so people providing answers know they have to detect and validate multiple addresses.

Comment: @NirajPaudel, I have added an answer. Kindly have a look at it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so here is a way to accomplish what you are trying to do

```
<html>
        <form action="" method="POST">

          E Mail:<br>
          <textarea name="email" id="email" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea><br><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['email'])){
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $email_array = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $email);
                //print_r($email_array);
                foreach ($email_array as $key => $value) {
                        if (!filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === true) {
                        //echo("$email is a valid email address");
                     echo "$value is invalid<br>";
                }

                } 
            }


        ?>
        </html>
```

Comment: How does this address the OP's desire to make the input multi-line?

Comment: It doesn't. It will invalidate the field afterwards, and the user will have o fill in the form again. For just one field, its enough, but I have many.